# SVN branch merge

Tags: svn, merge, tree, branch, conflict

I have a question about merging in Subversion. So I have a trunk and then two branches that come from the trunk.  So lets say I have a trunk and then branch A that was created from the trunk and then later branch B was created from the trunk.

Lets say then that I made changes to B and then changes to the trunk and then merged the trunk changes into B and checked into branch B.  I now want to merge to branch A, not to the trunk.  Is that possible to just merge branch B into branch A?  Or do I first have to merge branch B to the trunk then to branch A?

Comment: Certainly it is possible. Revisions is just changes in files, no magic there that prevents you from doing things. The question is: what changes do you want to merge into branch A?

Comment: I want to merge all the changes available on Branch B since it's creation and since branch A creation. As I mentioned above, Branch B at this time is up to date with TRUNK.

Comment: Then just go ahead: try to imagine what the svn merge command expresses: "take over all changes that happened to the specified url from revision `a` to revision `b`". Simple. No magic around. Always remember that the concept of a 'branch' or a 'trunk' does not have any technical meaning. It is just names, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge any branches you want

Answer (score 0):

You can merge revisions individually in SVN. So yeah, just select the revisions that you would like to merge from B to A and it should work just fine. If there are files missing from A that are present in B and you haven't yet merged their additions, then you might get a tree conflict. You can clear these by merging the missing files at the point where they were originally added to B.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing tree conflicts. Lets says I'm on branch A now. I can see the first revision on branch B by running svn log --stop-on-copy branchB and whatever revision# I see, then do I just need to run "svn merge -r rev#:HEAD http://url/branches/branchB"   (assuming im in branchA workspace).

Comment: Tree conflicts are usually a sign that something is being merged that is either not present or has since been deleted in the target branch. Ergo, you can't merge changes into something that is not present in the revision history. Try resolving the conflict by making sure that your source branch wholly coincides with your target branch as far the file structure is concerned, and then if need be, merge the revisions that have either added or deleted the files that the tree conflict complains about.